# iterate .net dictionary as object

Tags: c#, loops, object, dictionary, key

I have an interesting problem. I need to write a general (I'd use the word "generic" but that would conflict with what I'm after) routine that I can hand an instance of a dictionary object instance and iterate over the content of said object as a dictionary and return the content as literal values. The difficulty lies in that the method parameter will be of type "object", not dictionary.

What I need now and can't figure out how to do, is a way of iterating over a `Dictionary<K, V>` of arbitrary keys and values. Easy to do if you know the types going in, but as I say, the origin of the dictionary will be as an object where object.GetType().GetInterfaces() has typeof(IDictionary) in the results. I won't know (and shouldn't need to know) the dictionary key type or the value type.

My current need is to process something that is `Dictionary<string, SomeClass>`;. Once I get the list of keys I can use a foreach on each instance, figure out that it's a string and proceed from there. With the Values it'll be an instance of some class (the class will change but again, I can pass that off to another set of methods to extract the class, extract the properties of the class and extract those values).

The main point of the request is to obtain a method (or two or however many) that will allow me to iterate over a dictionary of unknown types and extract the keys and values, all without knowing the types at compile time. The above Dictionary; is just an example, I need to be able to pass any dictionary. At the moment, I'm not worried about edge cases like `Dictionary<Tuple<int, string, SomeOtherClass>, SomeClass>>` or things like that, if I can start with `Dictionary<string, SomeClass>;`, I can probably proceed from there.

It's getting the keys and values out in a form that I can process that I haven't figured out how to do yet.

Comment: What is wrong with for foreach over dictionary which will give you key/value pairs

Comment: Think about your question. The "foreach" is usually a "foreach (TYPE item in enumerable)" where item is either a key or a value. In particular since the only way I know the instance is a dictionary at all is by examining the interfaces, there isn't a way that I know of to declare the object as a dictionary and then reference the keys and values. Since I don't know the type, how can I declare  a foreach? If I could use the interfaces to declare a variable and cast it to the desired interface at runtime, problem solved. I don't know of a way to do that, do you?

Comment: `foreach(var keyValue in (Dictionary)someObject)`... metacubed's (+1) answer shows how to get to key/value directly and probably better suits your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you have access to the [`IDictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) interface on the object. You can then use [`get_Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ebzfbyx.aspx) and [`get_Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yxt5h4s.aspx) to access the keys and values respectively.

Also, `IDictionary<K,V>` derives from [`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) so you can also access the list of key-value pairs using a for-loop similar to lists.

EDIT - Clarification:

```
IDictionary inputAsDictionary = input as IDictionary;
if (inputAsDictionary != null)
{
    // Valid :  input is a dictionary.
    ICollection dictKeys = inputAsDictionary.Keys; // This is a list of all keys
    ICollection dictValues = inputAsDictionary.Values; // This is a list of all values

    // Iterate over all keys
    for(var dictKey in dictKeys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dictKey); // Print the key
        Type dictKeyType = dictKey.GetType(); // Get the type of key if required
        // ...
    }

    // Similarly, iterate over all values
    for(var dictValue in dictValues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dictValue); // Print the value
        Type dictValueType = dictValue.GetType(); // Get the type of value if required
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can also do this using the generic `Dictionary<K,V>` interface, but it gets a lot more complicated to get the types. You will need to call [Type.GenericTypeArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.generictypearguments.aspx) and go from there. The example I have shown seems simpler.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I *think* I know where you are going, but a code snippet as an example would help greatly. In the list of interfaces, I can see (debug mode - look at the content of the call from "propertyType.GetInterfaces()") that both "IDictionary" and "IDictionary`2" are in the list, but I'm not sure what, if anything, I can do with them.

Comment: Ok, that's great for getting the types of the keys and values, but (apologies for being dense here), what I need isn't the types so much as the actual values that make up the list of keys or values. For instance, if I have a Dictionary&lt;string, int&gt; that contains two entries {{"Key1", 1}, {"Key2", 2}}, I need to be able to fetch out the "Key1" and "Key2" and the 1 and 2 from the keys and values.

Comment: @Fred oh you already have those in the example above. Each `dictKey` is the actual value of the key i.e. "Key1", "Key2". Each `dictValue` is likewise the actual value i.e. 1, 2, etc.

Comment: (sound of hand smacking forehead)! Thanks - I've been too close to the problem and just flat missed that.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in marking this as "The Answer", I needed to expand on the basis of what was presented here to accomplish my goal - that being a method that I call "ToCode" which will take an object and spit out the necessary C# code to initialize an instance of said object at a later time. This is good for developing brown field development test mock data. Thanks for the guidance, it really helped!